# Should logic of Spark transformation and action need to be threadsafe?

Tags: java, apache-spark, thread-safety, rdd

This may be a stupid question. However, I would like to know if I have something like this - `rdd.mapPartitions(func)`. Should the logic in `func` be threadsafe?

Thanks

Comment: Since RDD operations are always immutable, the thread safety issue doesn't matter for the underlying function which transform RDD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no, it does not have to be thread safe.

The reason for this is that spark divides the data between partitions. It then creates a task for each partition and the function you write would run within that specific partition as a single threaded operation (i.e. no other thread would access the same data).

That said, you have to make sure you do not create thread "unsafety" manually by accessing resources which are not the RDD data. For example, if you create a static object and access that, it might cause issues as multiple tasks might run in the same executor (JVM) and access it as well. That said, you shouldn't be doing something like that to begin with unless you know exactly what you are doing...

Comment: What if `spark.task.cpus` is greater than `1 `? Each task can have multiple threads, and does it have race condition issue?

Comment: @jack. As far as I understand, a task is ALWAYS serial. That said, you may have a function in the task which you want to be explicitly multi threaded. You can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671644/how-does-spark-achieve-parallelism-within-one-task-on-multi-core-or-hyper-thread, or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104550/1547734

Answer (score 3):

Any function passed to the `mapPartitions` (or any other action or transformation) has to be thread safe. Spark on JVM (this is not necessarily true for guest languages) uses executor threads and doesn't guarantee any isolation between individual tasks.

This is particularly important when you use resources which are not initialized in the function, but passed with the closure like for example objects initialized in the main function, but referenced in the function.

It goes without saying you should not modify any of the arguments unless it is explicitly allowed.

Answer (score -3):

When you do "rdd.mapPartitions(func)", the func may actually execute in a different jvm!!! Thread does not have significance across JVM.

If you are running in local mode, and using global state or thread unsafe functions, the job might work as expected but the behaviours is not defined or supported.